# Sonata media bundle - get pdf file by name or change filename on update

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I currently use SonataAdminBundle and SonataMediaBundle.
I have a problem with the media bundle files because my pdf file is not saved with its name but with md5 or another format.

For example:

- media table
- id : 1
- name : iphone.pdf
- provider_reference : 9a0b7a35131e23f91666324562c52f08b7cb6604.pdf

I don't want to get my pdf by this:

```
9a0b7a35131e23f91666324562c52f08b7cb6604.pdf
```

but with its name ( `iphone.pdf` ).

I want to know if it's possible to:

- get the pdf file by name?

or

- save my pdf file with a particular name?

Answer (score 2):

use this in your Twig so you can download it with its name:

```
{{ path('sonata_media_download', {'id': (your media object here|sonata_urlsafeid)}) }}
```

To see it without download, I'm searching for that , I'll be back if I find something.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want get public URL for file in PHP-code, you can use something like this (code from my Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Helper\MediaHelper)

```
public function getPublicUrl(Media $media, $format = 'reference')
{
    if (!$media) {
        return '';
    }

    /** @var ImageProvider $provider */
    $provider = $this->container->get($media->getProviderName());
    $format = $provider->getFormatName($media, $format);

    return $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, $format);
}
```

If you need link in twig, you can find special helper in SonataMedia official docs (I forgot name of helper).

Comment: thx. but i need to get public url by pdf name, not generated pdf name ( like 9a0b7a35131e23f91666324562c52f08b7cb6604.pdf ) . phil

Comment: Generated filename is unique, origin name isnt so you cannt create route **/some/path/originName.pdf**.
If you need to open document by link, 
you should to create route /some/path/{{ docId }}/{{ docName }}
and use docId for find file.

Comment: public function someAction($id, $name)
{
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Media');
$doc = $repo->find($id);
if (null == $doc) {
 throw $this->createNotFoundException('Документ не найден');
}
$helper = new UploadMediaHelper($this->container);
$r = new BinaryFileResponse($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web' . $helper->getPublicUrl($doc));
$r->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
return $r;
}